# Mac can't find WiFi AP

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, wifi

Albergue in Spain asked me about their WiFi.  I have used the same access point (AP) last year with MacBook Pro (MBP), iPad, and iPhone.  Now, none of them are able to use it, and I have reason to believe the **LONG** Cat-5 cable has gone bad.  However, I took it to another room and plugged in another cable that has been running a working AP.  Plugged in there, my Nexus 5X phone can connect to it and `contact outside websites.  But a MacBook Pro **and** an iPad Pro cannot even see the AP.

This AP is driven from a DSL modem/router/AP which does let me surf.  I find it highly unlikely that this AP is capable of identifying and blocking all Apple devices, nor that the owners would hv any reason for setting it to do so (nor that they would even know how).

Nexus and MBP were in the same room, about 1.5 meters from the AP.  iPad Pro was one room away, about twelve meters, in a spot where it was able to detect the AP that I unplugged to plug in this one.

What might explain this?  The AP is currently routing packets on this cable for at least one device, but on the other cable, for no devices.

To clarify the layout:  DSL feeds device one, router/AP/modem.  Device one feeds devices two and three.  Three is router/AP but router ports not being used.  Two is normally on a **long** cat-5 cable and is only an AP.  It does not route packets there but the SSID can be detected.  Moved to swap with three, and it routes packets for a Nexus running Android, but MBP and iPad Pro cannot see the SSID.

UPDATE: We replaced the AP with a two-antenna router, and replaced the cable with a new one.  A tester verified that one wire of the old cable was open, and since we could not talk to the admin port of the AP, we don't trust it.  Now, the Macbook **still** says the SSID does not exist but the iPad uses it with no problem.  iPad bought in Spain; MBP bought in USA, **replacing** the one that worked last year with the old AP.

Does Apple intentionally disable European WiFi channels on machines sold in USA?  Or is there a bug or hardware problem?

Comment: I tried typing in the SSID as if it was a hidden one but the iPad Pro said it could not find it.

Comment: Does Apple not support European channel 13?  That's the setting on the one I can't find.

Comment: No, it's more than that.  I inadvertently reset the AP (dlink) to factory settings, and the Macbook can't find its SSID when the iPad can, all three sitting on the same end of the table.  And with the Macbook connected to the WIRED port of the AP, ifconfig says the port is active, but I can't get ping or http on it's admin port.